# Using sed to get text starting at a line number and ending with a reg expression pattern

Tags: bash, sed

I want to be able to extract text in a bash script using sed starting at a certain line number and ending at a given pattern. Right now I have `sed "${LINE_NUM}p;d" $FROM_FILE`, but that only returns the text on line number `$LINE_NUM`. What if I want to get text starting at `$LINE_NUM` going all the way down to some pattern of text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
sed -n "${LINE_NUM},/regex/p" "$FROM_FILE"
```

Be sure to use word boundary `\b` for text to get a perfect match instead of fuzzy.